# How to store tile maps into databases and use them for web mapping?

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, database

I am making a web map using leaflet and a lot of tile maps from raster files. When using `gdal2tile.py` to convert these rasters into tile maps, it will automatically create a bunch of directories and thousands of PNGs. Since I will have thousands of rasters to be tiled I think it might not be a good choice to save them this way. I am thinking is it possible to save them into database and query them when needed? I am using `Postgresql` and `PostGIS` for other functions of the map. So if `Postgresql` can handle this, it would be the best.

Comment: Having generated/static tiles (in your file system) isn't necessarily a bad thing, rendering them each time (for every new request) might have performance drawbacks. Do you need to always have the latest data in your tile dataset? Have a look at tile servers like Mapnik or MapServer, is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yeah, we might be going to implement data update to our app, but for now, we just want to plot all the data we have. Since you said that having all the images in the file system is not bad compare to storing them in the database. Then I am good I think.